# Group Array Values By Key

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays in PHP:

```
Array1
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
)
Array2
(
    [0] => 18
    [1] => 19
    [2] => 20
)
```

`Array1` contains the Ids of Delivery Addresses.
`Array2` contains the Ids of Contacts.

`Array1` and `Array2` are 'aligned' so that Contact 18 (`Array2[0]`) resides at Delivery Address Id #1 (`Array1[0]`) (and so on).

What I would like is use the unique values of `Array1` as array keys for `Array3`, and the values of `Array2` used as the array values `Array3`.

The end result being that Contacts are 'grouped' by their Delivery Address.

Like so:

```
Array 3
(
   [1] = array (
                 [0] => 18
               )
   [2] = array (
                 [0] => 19
                 [1] => 20
               )
)
```

Comment: Kudos to @hsz for providing a good solution so quickly, but I feel like mentioning this sounds like terrible design.

Comment: Agreed - it's not ideal, but is designed to work within a very specific scenario (AJAX request sending POST). That said, if you have any suggestions, please let me know :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$array3 = array();
foreach ( $array1 as $k => $v ) {
    if ( !isset($array3[$v]) )
        $array3[$v] = array();

    $array3[$v][] = $array2[$k];
}

var_dump($array3);
```

Comment: Thanks hsz. This results in exactly what I was asking for. And kudos for the speed of answering (<2mins) :)

Comment: Enjoy and have a nice day. ;)